# Finding the quotient and remainder when $(2x^3+4x-45)$ is divided by $(x+6)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Question:
>
> Find the quotient and remainder of the following division $$(2x^3+4x-45)\div(x+6)$$

My friend asked me this question, for what I've seen, it looks like cubic equation, so I tried to factorise the equation to solve it. It didn't work, how do I solve it?

Comment: Search up on polynomial long division.

Comment: Try with synthetic division. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division#Regular_synthetic_division

Comment: Look up regular long division first.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem by using synthetic division [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division)]. We begin by finding the zero of the divisor $x+6$, which is clearly $\color{teal}{-6}$.
\begin{array}{c|rrrr}
&2 &0 &4 &-45\\
\color{teal}{-6} &\downarrow &-12 &72 &-456\\
\hline &\color{blue}{2} &\color{green}{-12} &\color{maroon}{76} &\color{red}{-501}
\end{array}
The quotient is thus $\color{blue}{2}x^2\color{green}{-12}x+\color{maroon}{76}$ with a remainder of $\color{red}{-501}$. Let us verify our solution.
$$P=\left(x+6\right)\cdot\left(2x^2-12x+76-\frac{501}{x+6}\right)$$
Let us find the product $P$, which should be the original dividend.
\begin{align}
P&=2x^3-12x^2+76x-\frac{501\cdot x}{x+6}+12x^2-72x+456-\frac{501\cdot6}{x+6}\\
&=2x^3+4x+456-\frac{501(x+6)}{(x+6)}\\
&=2x^3+4x-45
\end{align}
This is the original dividend, so we have solved the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=2x^3+4x-45$. By the remainder theorem, the remainder is $f(-6)=-501$. Set
\begin{equation*}
2x^3+4x-45=(ax^2+bx+c)(x+6)-501.
\end{equation*} By comparing coefficients, it is easy to see that $a=2$, $b=-12$ and $c=76$. In other words, the quotient is $2x^2-12x+76$.